# Pandas Resampling error: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, resampling

When using pandas' `resample` function on a DataFrame in order to convert tick data to OHLCV, a resampling error is encountered.

How should we solve the error?

[image]

```py
# Resample data into 30min bins
bars = data.Price.resample('30min', how='ohlc')
volumes = data.Volume.resample('30min', how='sum')
```

This gives the error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Convert the integer timestamps in the index to a DatetimeIndex:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, unit='s')
```

This interprets the integers as seconds since the Epoch.

---

For example, given

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Timestamp':[1313331280, 1313334917, 1313334917, 1313340309, 1313340309], 
     'Price': [10.4]*3 + [10.5]*2, 'Volume': [0.779, 0.101, 0.316, 0.150, 1.8]})
data = data.set_index(['Timestamp'])
#             Price  Volume
# Timestamp                
# 1313331280   10.4   0.779
# 1313334917   10.4   0.101
# 1313334917   10.4   0.316
# 1313340309   10.5   0.150
# 1313340309   10.5   1.800

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, unit='s')
```

yields

```
                     Price  Volume
2011-08-14 14:14:40   10.4   0.779
2011-08-14 15:15:17   10.4   0.101
2011-08-14 15:15:17   10.4   0.316
2011-08-14 16:45:09   10.5   0.150
2011-08-14 16:45:09   10.5   1.800
```

Then

```
ticks = data.ix[:, ['Price', 'Volume']]
bars = ticks.Price.resample('30min').ohlc()
volumes = ticks.Volume.resample('30min').sum()
```

can be computed:

```
In [368]: bars
Out[368]: 
                     open  high   low  close
2011-08-14 14:00:00  10.4  10.4  10.4   10.4
2011-08-14 14:30:00   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
2011-08-14 15:00:00  10.4  10.4  10.4   10.4
2011-08-14 15:30:00   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
2011-08-14 16:00:00   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
2011-08-14 16:30:00  10.5  10.5  10.5   10.5

In [369]: volumes
Out[369]: 
2011-08-14 14:00:00    0.779
2011-08-14 14:30:00      NaN
2011-08-14 15:00:00    0.417
2011-08-14 15:30:00      NaN
2011-08-14 16:00:00      NaN
2011-08-14 16:30:00    1.950
Freq: 30T, Name: Volume, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is designed for time-series data, as the error says, `resample()` works only if the index is datetime, timedelta or period. The following are a few common ways this error may show up.

However, you can also use the `on=` parameter to **use a column as grouper**, without having a datetime index.

```py
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], unit='s')
bars = df.resample('30min', on='Timestamp')['Price'].ohlc()
volumes = df.resample('30min', on='Timestamp')['Volume'].sum()
```

[image: res1]

If you have a **MultiIndex dataframe** where one of the index is datetime, then you can use `level=` to select that level as the grouper.

```py
volumes = df.resample('30min', level='Timestamp')['Volume'].sum()
```

[image: res2]

You can also use `resample.agg` to pass multiple methods.

```py
resampled = df.resample('30min', on='Timestamp').agg({'Price': 'ohlc', 'Volume': 'sum'})
```

[image: res3]