# Python - calculating weekly and monthly returns from daily data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
sp_data.head()
Out[21]: 
         Date       Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close  Volume
0  1927-12-30  17.660000  17.660000  17.660000  17.660000  17.660000       0
1  1928-01-03  17.760000  17.760000  17.760000  17.760000  17.760000       0
2  1928-01-04  17.719999  17.719999  17.719999  17.719999  17.719999       0
3  1928-01-05  17.549999  17.549999  17.549999  17.549999  17.549999       0
4  1928-01-06  17.660000  17.660000  17.660000  17.660000  17.660000       0
```

which contains daily data, and I would like to get the returns per week, per month, per 3, 6 months etc. I tried the following:

```
sp_data_daily_returns = sp_data['Close'].pct_change()
sp_data_monthly_returns = sp_data['Close'].resample('M').ffill().pct_change()
```

but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: you need make resample on datetime series.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Resampling error: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857680/pandas-resampling-error-only-valid-with-datetimeindex-or-periodindex)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, we apply any conversion on date we have to check its data-type. So error you are getting is based on data type error, you can change it using `pd.to_datetime()`.

You can have a look at this too:

[Pandas Resampling error: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857680/pandas-resampling-error-only-valid-with-datetimeindex-or-periodindex)